# XSLT recursive pass-through output with template appliance

Tags: xml, xslt, recursion

I'm a newcomer to XSLT, XSL and XML manipulation techniques. Right now i do some simple transformations to this example XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="main.xsl"?>
<content base-url="../../../">
    <article title="TITLE_HERE" timestamp="TIME_HERE">
        <p>SOME TEXT HERE <a href="URL.xml">LINKTEXT</a>.</p>
    </article>
</content>
```

Applying this 'main.xsl' transformation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<xsl:output method="xml"
            version="1.0"
            encoding="UTF-8"
            doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd"
            doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
            indent="yes"/>

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param  name="base"
            select="/content/@base-url"/>

<!-- PAGE TEMPLATE -->
<xsl:template match="/content">
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
           ...
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="content">
                <xsl:apply-templates match="article"/>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<!-- ARTICLE NODE TEMPLATE -->
<xsl:template match="article">
    <h2>
        <xsl:value-of select="@title"/>
    </h2>
    <h3>
        <xsl:value-of select="@timestamp"/>
    </h3>
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As you can see, copy-of is used. Problem is with anchor link. When using copy-of, i cannot use concat function, as was using within template:

```
<xsl:template match="a">
    <a href="{concat($base, @href)}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </a>
</xsl:template>
```

So, basically, there is need to use some recursion that will output whole nodes (tags and attributes) but without childs (text and other), recursively parsing them with assigned templates.

How can this be done?

Comment: Search for "identity transformation" or "identity template" - there are literally hundreds of examples of this technique in other SO questions (and elsewhere on the web) and there's an example [in the XSLT specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#copying).

Comment: Quote _"there is need to use some recursion"_: in XSLT, recursion comes naturally by using matching templates and `xsl:copy` for shallow copy of the current node. LingaMurthy's answer shows exactly how that is done, without you having to explicitly write recursive functions or call-templates. The `xsl:copy-of` you use makes an instant copy of all children, without processing them further, making it useless if you want to do something with those children (as in your example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following XSLT:
new template that matches "node() | @*" copies the the nodes and attributes as it is. And instead of copy-of I've used apply-templates:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<xsl:output method="xml"
        version="1.0"
        encoding="UTF-8"
        doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd"
        doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
        indent="yes"/>

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param  name="base"
        select="/content/@base-url"/>

<!-- PAGE TEMPLATE -->
<xsl:template match="/content">
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
       ...
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="content">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="article"/>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a">
    <a href="{concat($base, @href)}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </a>
</xsl:template>

<!-- ARTICLE NODE TEMPLATE -->
<xsl:template match="article">
    <h2>
        <xsl:value-of select="@title"/>
    </h2>
    <h3>
        <xsl:value-of select="@timestamp"/>
    </h3>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: When I did it also added the namespace declarations to every single node. How can I avoid that?

Comment: @DaniilShevelev If you are talking about the namespace, `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml`, you can remove it from the XSLT in my answer. Since this namespace is the default namespace in XSLT, the elements created fall in it.